# conversion of entire data frame into standard normal form in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am having dataframe testsample of 300 rows and 70 columns.
How to convert entire dataframe into standard normal form.

i have written the following R code snippets:

```
normalization<- function(testsample){
newSample<-data.frame(1:nrow(testSample))
for(j in 1:ncol(testsample)){
  mu<-mean(testsample[,j])
  sigma<-sd(testsample[,j])
  colName<- names(testsample)
      for(i in 1:nrow(testsample)){
        newSample$colName[j] <- transmute(testsample,colName[j]=((testsample[i,j]-mu)/sigma)           

     }
  }

print(newSample)
return(newSample)
}
z<-normalization(testsample)
```

in the line where i used transmute function i got the error for colName[j].
i understand the error. i am trying to evaluate both LHS and RHS at the same time, which is not possible, and it simply replaces the values.

without using any r package how to solve and convert the entire data frame into standard normal form.

Comment: How about using function `scale`?

Comment: @ David, for some columns in a dataframe it returns NA value.can u explain??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following line should work:

```
newSample <- testSample 
for(j in 1:ncol(testsample)){ 
  mu <- mean(testsample[,j]) 
  sigma <- sd(testsample[,j]) 
  newSample[,j] <- (newSample[,j]-mu)/sigma) 
}
```

Otherwise try dropping the index `i` within `transmute`.

I have no experience with `scale`, but that might be a better and simpler idea.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment, use `scale` function:

```
x <- matrix(runif(300*70), 300, 70)
x <- as.data.frame(x)
dim(x)
# [1] 300  70

y <- scale(x)

head(apply(y, 2, mean))
#            V1            V2            V3            V4            V5            V6 
# -6.641678e-17  5.092425e-17 -4.435159e-17  8.974583e-17  8.300724e-17  9.999023e-17 

head(apply(y, 2, sd))
# V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 
#  1  1  1  1  1  1
```